# 2-Microphone Android Phones for ASR purposes?

Tags: android, nexus-one, adp, noise-reduction

Is the Nexus One the only Android phone having 2 microphones?

I know that the 2nd microphone is intended for helping noise cancellation and I need this feature for my software development project.

I am wondering whether the Nexus One is the only such Android phone. That is, if I need to program for this feature, must I purchase a Nexus One only?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. Any Android programmer in the ASR field could benefit from having this useful piece of information in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Motorola Droid](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-DROID-US-EN.alt), [Droid 2](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-DROID-X-US-EN.alt), and [Droid X](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-DROID-2-US-EN.alt) all have dual microphone noise reduction as well. However, I am not sure if this always enabled when the microphone is active, or if it only works during calls. Also, I'm not sure how that would help with [text to speech (TTS)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Speech_synthesis). Do you mean [speech to text/speech recognition](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Speech_recognition)?

If you need GSM phones, look (depending on your location, inside or outside of the US) at the [Motorla Charm](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.MOTOROLA-CHARM-with-MOTOBLUR-US-EN.alt), [Backflip](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/XW-EN/Consumer-Products-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-BACKFLIP-with-MOTOBLUR-XW-EN.alt), [Milestone 2](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/XW-EN/Consumer-Products-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Milestone-2-XW-EN.alt), and [Droid 2 global (CDMA & GSM)](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/DROID2-Global-US-EN). I just noticed that it may seem like I'm pushing Motorola. I'm not. These were the only phones which clearly stated they had two microphones for noise cancellation that I could find after quite a bit of Googling.

Comment: Yes, I meant ASR (automatic speech recognition), sorry for the mistake (I just fixed the title from TTS to ASR). Thank you for this information. I noticed these are all CDMA phones. Are there GSM phones (like the Nexus One) that have them, too?

Comment: I have added GSM options to the question above.

Comment: Thank you. I am still using the Android emulator for software development but soon I will need to test the software on a real phone. These options may help me lower the cost.